# Package conditional import

Tags: python-3.x

I'm writing a package that controls the firmware of our devices. The package wraps function calls to a shared library (Linux and Windows). The packages contains many modules that encapsulates functions from the shared library wrapper. The package will be use internally and potentially by clients.

In order to speed up development, we need to create a mock wrapper that emulates the calls to the shared library. Here is an example of the structure:

```
import device_wrapper
import Module_A, ... Module_Z

class Device_0:
   def __init__(self):
       self.sub_device_0 = Module_A
       self.sub_device_n = Module_Z
```

Each module import different functions from the wrapper. The users can use any modules as well as the "Devices" classes.

Now, I'm looking for a way to use any modules of the package, while importing the mock wrapper in some cases and importing the real wrapper in other cases.
Something along the lines of:

```
if mock_enable:
    import mock as device_wrapper
else:
    import device_wrapper
import Module_A, ... Module_Z

class Device_0:
   def __init__(self):
       self.sub_device_0 = Module_A
       self.sub_device_n = Module_Z
```

Where mock_enable would be imported by all the other modules and would be a module that manages the imports.

Is there a better way to do what I want to do?
Am I missing any pitfalls?

Comment: I looked at other posts, thinking about __builtins__, global variables, but I was not sure that I should go down that lane.

Comment: Seems like the standard thing to do. But make sure that `mock_enable` is properly initialized before any other module imports it.